# How to import json file into indexeddb?

Tags: json, indexeddb

I am doing an app that store some data in the IndexedDB, but I want to load first some data that is in my json file.

Here is my json file:

```
{
  "ciudades":[
    {
      "ciudad":"Asuncion",
      "latitud":-25.2985296,
      "longitud":-57.6710677
    },
    {
      "ciudad":"Caaguazu",
      "latitud":-25.465034,
      "longitud":-56.0183859
    },
    {
      "ciudad":"Ciudad del Este",
      "latitud":-25.4933441,
      "longitud":-54.6710438
    },
     {
      "ciudad":"San Pedro",
      "latitud":-24.1586759,
      "longitud":-56.636503
    },
     {
      "ciudad":"Pedro Juan Caballero",
      "latitud":-22.5450875,
      "longitud":-55.7618963
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide json string so it will help us.

Comment: Which part do you have problems with? Getting the json into an object or storing an object into an IndexedDB objectstore? Where is your json file located? On the server or client?

Comment: I can get the json into an object and show in the view. But the problem is how to store that object in the indexedDB. My file is on the client side

Comment: Post the code that you have tried and the error you are getting. If you haven't tried anything yet because you don't know IDB, maybe start with the example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Structuring_the_database

Answer (score 6):

you follow step

step 1 [read mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/IndexedDB)

step 2 create indexedDB

```
var ciudades = [
{
  "ciudad":"Asuncion",
  "latitud":-25.2985296,
  "longitud":-57.6710677
},
{
  "ciudad":"Caaguazu",
  "latitud":-25.465034,
  "longitud":-56.0183859
},
{
  "ciudad":"Ciudad del Este",
  "latitud":-25.4933441,
  "longitud":-54.6710438
},
 {
  "ciudad":"San Pedro",
  "latitud":-24.1586759,
  "longitud":-56.636503
},
 {
  "ciudad":"Pedro Juan Caballero",
  "latitud":-22.5450875,
  "longitud":-55.7618963
}
];

var IDBSetting = {
    name: "indexedDBName",
    version: 1,
    tables: [{
        tableName: "ciudades",
        keyPath: "seq",
        autoIncrement: true,
        index: ["ciudad", "latitud", "longitud],
        unique: [false, false, false]
    }]
};

! function() {
    console.log("indexeDB init");

    var req = indexedDB.open(IDBSetting.name, IDBSetting.version);

    req.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log("indexedDB open success");
    };

    req.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("indexed DB open fail");
    };

    //callback run init or versionUp
    req.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        console.log("init onupgradeneeded indexedDB ");
        var db = event.target.result;

        for (var i in IDBSetting.tables) {
            var OS = db.createObjectStore(IDBSetting.tables[i].tableName, {
                keyPath: IDBSetting.tables[i].keyPath,
                autoIncrement: IDBSetting.tables[i].autoIncrement
            });

            for (var j in IDBSetting.tables[i].index) {
                OS.createIndex(IDBSetting.tables[i].index[j], IDBSetting.tables[i].index[j], {
                    unique: IDBSetting.tables[i].unique[j]
                });
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

step 3 addData

```
var IDBFuncSet = {
    //write
    addData: function(table, data) {
        var req = indexedDB.open(IDBSetting.name, IDBSetting.version);

        req.onsuccess = function(event) {
            try {
                console.log("addData indexedDB open success");
                var db = req.result;
                var transaction = db.transaction([table], "readwrite");
                var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(table);
                var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.add(data);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("addDataFunction table or data null error");
                console.log(e);
            }

            objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                //console.log("Call data Insert success");
            }
            objectStoreRequest.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log("addData error");
            }
        };

        req.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("addData indexed DB open fail");
        };
    }
}

for(var i in ciudades){
   IDBFuncSet.addData("ciudades",ciudades[i]);
}
```

step 4 getData

```
IDBFuncSet.getAllData = function(arr, table) {
    try {
        var req = indexedDB.open(IDBSetting.name, IDBSetting.version);

        req.onsuccess = function(event) {
            var db = req.result;
            var transaction = db.transaction([table], "readonly");
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(table);

            var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.openCursor();

            objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                var cursor = event.target.result;
                if (cursor) {
                    arr.push(cursor.value);
                    cursor.continue();
                } else {

                }
            }
        };
        req.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("getAllData indexed DB open fail");
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
var ciudadesArr = [];
IDBFuncSet.getAllData(ciudadesArr, "ciudades");

console.log(ciudadesArr);
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I've done mine, [thanks to the android-indexeddb](https://github.com/bramski/angular-indexedDB) package.

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['indexedDB'])
    .config(function($indexedDBProvider) {
        $indexedDBProvider
            .connection('dbName')
            .upgradeDatabase(1, function(event, db, tx) {
                var objStore = db.createObjectStore('storeOne', { keyPath: 'stop_id' });
                objStore.createIndex('store_id', 'store_id', { unique: false });
            })
            // the next upgradeDatabase() function is necessary if you 
            // wish to create another datastore
            .upgradeDatabase(2, function(event, db, tx) {
                var secondObjectStore = db.createObjectStore('storeTwo', { keyPath: 'my_id' });
                secondObjectStore.createIndex('another_id', 'another_id', { unique: false });
            });
    })
```

Then in my controller:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$indexedDB', function($scope, $http, $indexedDB) {
        $scope.objects = [];
        var loadJSON = function(file_name) { ... //load the json file in here}

        $indexedDB.openStore('storeOne', function(store) {
            var loaded = loadJSON('file_name.json');
            store.upsert(loaded).then(function(e) {
                console.log('added successfully');
            });
        });        

        $indexedDB.openStore('times', function(store) {
            var loaded = loadJSON('file_name.json');
            store.upsert(loaded).then(function(e) {
                console.log('added successfully');
            });
        });
    }]);
```

Check out the project page to learn more of the tricks up this package's sleeves.

Although this angular-indexeddb page supports queries, for advanced queries like joins, you might wanna [consider ydn-db](https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db)

Getting some pretty nice workflow with both packages.

For the loadJSON() function, it could be something like this:

```
var loadJSON = function(file_name) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../data/' + file_name,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(res_data) {
            data = res_data;
            console.log('Loaded ' + file_name + ' nicely');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('error happened');
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), but that doesn't seem to be a solid standard yet.

What I do at the moment, is have the user open the file, copy it's contents to Clipboard, and paste it into a TextArea element on my web page.

In JavaScript I add a listener to the TextArea's change event and parse the text content into JSON, which is then written to indexedDB.